# Photography swag for top users

Tags: discussion, swag

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you have at least 950 reputation and are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://photo.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Photography Stack Exchange t-shirt in your size
- Photography Stack Exchange die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: photo.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: photo.stackexchange.com sticker]

### And also…

(There may also be another cool little Photography Stack Exchange item included. Stay tuned..)

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store soon as well)</sub>

Comment: Cool! Thank you! :D

Comment: Always nice to be appreciated :)

Comment: This is great - thanks!

Comment: nice. Though not too fond of the logo centered on the T-shirt, prefer them on the breast(pocket) as it's a bit more understated (maybe make that an option in the store version if the printer can do it).

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm looking forward to wearing that!

Comment: Cool, muchos gracias. I suppose I'd better put a valid e-mail address on my profile, currently it's just there to make my avatar icon look good! :)

Comment: Does this apply to international users, too?

Comment: @sam yes we ship internationally.

Comment: JEALOUS! Darn you people that do not upvote (or vote period!)

Comment: Yay! I'm on page two! Thanks for this initiative!

Comment: Ooh cool!  I am on page two, but barely, when is/was the list set?

Comment: @seanmc you could always earn some more reputation to ensure your eligibility ;)

Comment: I have! I was just wondering if a snapshot of the list was (or will be) taken at a certain date.  (I'm still on page 2!)

Comment: Just curious, has anybody been contacted yet?  Pretty sure I've been on page two the entire time but haven't heard anything, and it's been a couple of months now?

Comment: @seanmc I just sent an email to the email address you used to register on SE. Please let me know if you didn't get it.

Comment: @seanmc - It looks like they went out!

Comment: @Laura I still haven't received any email, I am still on page 2. Do I need to register somewhere to be eligible or just wait for the email?

Comment: I received an email about this back in October but haven't received any swag! I'm not greedy but would like to check if something was sent out?

Comment: @ShutterBug I'll look into it.

Comment: @MaynardCase They just went out last week; we had some trouble with the t-shirts and wanted everything perfect. Please allow at least another week since it's an international shipment to get to you, but if you still don't have it after another week or so, let me know.

Comment: @Laura - many thanks, will look forward to it turning up!

Comment: @ShutterBug I sent an email to the email address you used to sign up for Stack Exchange. Please let me know if you didn't receive it.

Comment: @Laura Thanks, I got the mail and replied! Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I've just received the package. Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, is the cloth really the 18% gray one? Looks a little warmer to me, but probably it's just electric light at home.

Comment: @jetxee - Yes it is 18% grey as far as I can tell, but maybe this link will help ease your worries : http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/19431/4892

Answer (score 5):

Thanks very much!

[image]

Comment: The signed letter was a nice touch... thanks!

Comment: I especially liked the Spudz cleaner - it's 18% grey so you can use it set an accurate white balance.

Comment: Yes, thanks from me too. (Huh; it feels weird to make a "me too" post on Stack Exchange, even if it is Meta!)

Answer (score 1):

Received down under, thanks Jeff!

Answer (score 1):

I've just recieved it. Thank you very much!

[image: photo.stackexchange.com gifts]

The microfiber cleaner cloth is great!

[image: photo.stackexchange.com gifts — Spudz cleaner open]

Answer (score 1):

Received everything in good shape :) thanks...

Answer (score 0):

finally got it last weekend. Shame the T was an S, and my size is XXL, but the gesture is much appreciated :)

Comment: we'll see if we can get that fixed for you, apologies!

Comment: got it, thanks for the quick work :)